# Cannot do "type is" tests on dict_keys / dict_values / dict_items?

Tags: python-3.x

Is it possible to test Python 3's *dict_keys*, *dict_values*, and *dict_items* built-in types with a "type is" statement?

It's easy to get a given built-in's type (in this example a *float*):

```
>>> type(4.5)
<class 'float'>
```

And use a "type is" statement to test its type:

```
>>> type(4.5) is float
True
>>> type(4.5) is int
False
```

Now I'll create a simple Python dictionary:

```
simpleDict = {
    'firstKey' : 'firstValue',
    'secondKey' : 'secondValue',
    }
```

It's easy to list a dict's  *keys*, *values*, or in this example *items*:

```
>>> simpleDict.items()
dict_items([('secondKey', 'secondValue'), ('firstKey', 'firstValue')])
```

And get the type of one of the *dict_* built-in types for that dictionary:

```
>>> type(simpleDict.items())
<class 'dict_items'>
```

But now I can't figure out how to use a "type is" statement to test that built-in type:

```
>>> type(simpleDict.items()) is dict_items
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'dict_items' is not defined
```

There's no practical reason I need to do this, I'm simply curious why the *dict* built-in types are reported as "not defined", and thus apparently not testable(?) with a "type is" test.

Comment: You could do  `d.items().__class__ is {}.items().__class__`, why do you want to do this?

Comment: "why do you want to do this?" As I said, there's no practical reason -- I'm simply curious why the "dict_" types behave differently than other built-ins in "type is" tests.

Comment: The dict is a builtin type,  the .items, .values etc.. are  methods on the dict. So you are really comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: "...are methods on the dict." That's starting to make a little sense. I was / am just confused because "type()" returned a type but then I couldn't use that type in a "type is" test.

Comment: Because it is not a builtin type. Everything has a type in python, just not everything is a builtin type. What would you expect `dict_items` to do if it were available?

Comment: One of the things that confused me was this bit in the Python 3 "Built-in Types" page: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views

Comment: That is a subsection to https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict, it is giving you info about the builtin dict type. That discusses view objects which is what you get in python3 when you can .keys, .items etc..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Padraic Cunningham said in the comments, you can use the following test to check for dict_items equality:

```
>>> type(simpleDict.items()) is {}.items().__class__
True
```

This also works for `keys()` and `values()`:

```
>>> type(simpleDict.keys()) is {}.keys().__class__
True
>>> type(simpleDict.values()) is {}.values().__class__
True
```

In general, to perform the "type is" test on a class, initialize an empty object of the class, and get the `__class__` member of the object to use for comparing against.